# use wp_get_theme() to get theme author name

Tags: wp-get-theme

As of wordpress 3.4 we're supposed to use wp_get_theme to return theme data.

```
$theme = wp_get_theme();

//var_dump($theme);

echo $theme->Author;
```

despite the var_dump indicating the correct string, $theme->Author always returns a hyperlink with the author's name, but linked to the author's site.  how can i get just the theme's author name?

Comment: I just upgraded to 3.4.1 to check this issue but i got just author's name and no hyperlink

    `$theme = wp_get_theme();
    var_dump($theme->Author);
`
this is what i got:

> string 'the WordPress team' (length=18)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use just the header string, call `display()` instead and set the second parameter to `FALSE` to suppress markup.

```
// FALSE for no markup
$theme->display( 'Author', FALSE );
```

What you see in your `var_dump()` are *private* properties. If you print `$theme->Author` the magic [`__get()`](http://php.net/__get) method is called and this calls `display()` without the second parameter for `$markup`.

Comment: thanks toscho... that does it.  i guess i have a lot to learn about OOP and "private" properties.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. I could reproduce the issue on my Wordpress 3.4.1 installation. Not sure if this is a bug; will need to dig into the core wordpress code to see how WP_Theme object is built and values are returned. For now, I think we're left with an option to use PHP string Parser functions and extract Author name.